# Python coding on datatypes i.e. for complex number arithmetic

Tags: python-3.x

In Python -

```
x3 = 23/2j
print(x3)
#output = -11.5j
```

and when

```
x3 = 23j/2
print(x3)
#output = 11.5j
```

whats the reason

Comment: Because `1/1j=-1j`? Why are your surprised?

Answer (score 1):

see, value of j is sq-root of -1, and so value of j-square j^2 = -1

Multiple both numerator and denominator by j in first equation

`x3 = (23 * j)/ (2j * j)`

=> `x3 = 23j/(-2)` because j-square = -1

=> `x3 = -23j/2`

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have 23j/2 i.e. a complex number and if you want j in denominator, you can shift it to denominator but the condition is you have to place a negative sign as it is an imaginary number( For ex. 2+3j, here 2 is real and 3 is imaginary part of the equation. You can also write it as 2-3/j)
so your number becomes -23/2j.
I hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: You cannot write `2-3/j`. `j` is is not a number on its own, it is a part of the complex number notation.

Comment: @DYZ We can shift complex number i.e. 1j in this case, from denominator to numerator and vice versa by just reversing its sign. here is the explanation video i got for you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz9q8rlsFiY , start watching from 0.45 sec.

Comment: I know we can. But `j` is illegal both in Python (where it must be `1j`) and in math (where it must be `i`). So, no, you cannot write `2-3/j`.

Comment: @DYZ So you mean j is not equal to 1j. haha NYC and for your kind information in maths you can write 'i' as well as 'j'. The square of both will be equal to -1. if you are misunderstanding my ans its 2-(3/j). I have not written (2-3)/j. Obviously we cannot do that.

Answer (score -1):

It's to do with syntax/representation of the complex part. (i.e. the `#j` is one single unit)

1. `23/2j = 23/(2j) = -11.5j` and **NOT** `(23/2)*j`.
2. `23j/2 = (23j)/2 = 11.5j`

Comment: This has nothing to do with grouping. `j` is not a number on its own, it is a part of the complex number notation. There is no such thing as `#j`.

Comment: @DYZ You are right. I used the term "grouping" to explain easily, cause I believe that's how the OP was seeing it. Edited